# how do I add a dockerfile to my repo in devops?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

I have a dockerfile that i want to add do my repo/pipeline in DevOps. I don't know how to add it.. Do I have to use visual studios or can I just do it in the cmd prompt?
[image]

this is what the dockerfile contains:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
COPY target/*.jar /home/app/demoapi.jar
ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-jar", "/home/app/demoapi.jar" ]
```

I've added a file to my repo in DevOps through cmd prompt and now I'm stuck on how to add my dockerfile to that repo. I want to know if I can do it without visual studios and add it through cmd prompt.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can click 3 dots button, create a new file, name it dockerfile and paste your code.
Or you can use Git, clone repo locally, add your file to the repo on your pc and push it to azure devops.